# How do i load, render and trasnform 2D images using Direct3D 11 API?

Tags: c++, 2d, directx, sprites, directx11

In my small game project using DirectX 11 API, I created a Direct3D device, and can draw 3D meshes, using web tutorials and a book. But I cannot figure out how to load, transform (rotate, scale, resize) and draw 2D sprites (loaded from PNG files, for example).

How can I do this?

I'd prefer to use no third-party libraries.

Comment: @Anko 
 
Do no change question title, as you change the meaning

Comment: I don't really see the difference. Loading, rendering and transforming are a pretty good description of a sprite API. What meaning is changed?

Comment: That i don't need any library, API or framework, except native d3d. there is a diff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider this [first-party library](https://github.com/Microsoft/DXUT); it is from MS, so if it is not-third-party enough for you, it will make your life considerably easier. It provides an interface to DX11 that is very similar to XNA. Specifically, SpriteBatch, SpriteFont, etc..

[Rastertek](http://www.rastertek.com/dx11tut11.html) and [Reimer's](http://www.riemers.net/) are generally helpful.

For Rastertek, I linked directly to their DX11 2D tutorial, but the site is pretty comprehensive.

Reimer's is DX9 and/or XNA, but covers many concepts that you can probably adapt to DX11 yourself. The processes are usually similar.

Comment: Rastertek Tutorial Rocks. I think i ll found out how can i create ID3D11ShaderResourceView from images types different than DDS after some time...

Comment: Jon linked to DXUT, when he should have linked to [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929). Look at DirectX Tool Kit's WICTextureLoader for code that loads an SRV from non-DDS files...